Unable to Save Cookie in Deployed Vercel Frontend with Railway Backend (MERN)
I'm having trouble with cookie storage for my MERN stack app after deployment. When I run my frontend locally, everything works fine — I can see the cookie in the developer tools and use it as expected. However, when I log in through my deployed frontend on Vercel, the cookie does not appear in the browser.
I'm unable to see my cookie in the browser, and I don't know why. I've tried everything to fix it. I'm storing my access token in the React state, so when I reload the page, it requests a new access token, which works as expected. The issue is with my refresh token, which is stored in a cookie. Although I can't see the cookie in the developer tools, the refresh token seems to exist because I'm able to successfully request a new access token. However, if I close and restart my browser, the refresh token no longer works, and I'm unable to retrieve a new access token.
Setup:
Frontend: Deployed on Vercel
Backend: Deployed on Railway
Cookie Configuration: I’m using httpOnly: true, secure: true, sameSite: "None", and credentials: true.
here is mine app.js of backend :
// Configure CORS
app.use(cors({
    origin: process.env.CORS_ORIGIN,
    credentials: true,
}));

// Handle preflight requests for all routes
app.options('*', cors());

here is mine controller :
const loginUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password, rememberMe, recaptchaValue } = req.body;

  if (![email, password].every(Boolean)) {
    throw new ApiError(400, "All fields are required, including reCAPTCHA");
  }
  if (![email, password, recaptchaValue].every(Boolean)) {
    throw new ApiError(400, "All fields are required, including reCAPTCHA");
  }

  const recaptchaSecret = process.env.RECAPTCHA_SECRET;
  const recaptchaResponse = await axios.post(
    `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify`,
    {},
    {
      params: {
        secret: recaptchaSecret,
        response: recaptchaValue,
      },
    }
  );

  const { success, score } = recaptchaResponse.data;

  if (!success || (score && score < 0.5)) {
    throw new ApiError(400, "reCAPTCHA verification failed");
  }

  const user = await User.findOne({
    $or: [{ email }, { username: email }],
  });
  if (!user) {
    throw new ApiError(404, "User doesn't exist");
  }

  // if (!user.isVerified) {
  // throw new ApiError(401, "Please verify your email to login");
  // }

  const passwordCheck = await user.isPasswordCorrect(password);
  if (!passwordCheck) {
    throw new ApiError(401, "Invalid user credentials");
  }
  const { accessToken, refreshToken } = await GenerateRefreshAccessToken(
    user._id,
    rememberMe
  );

  const options = {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    sameSite: "None",
    maxAge: rememberMe ? 6 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 : 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  };

  return res
    .cookie("refresh_token", refreshToken, options)
    .status(200)
    .json(
      new ApiResponse(200, { user, accessToken }, "User logged in successfully")
    );
});

May you please help me to fix the code , im deploying mine mern for the first time , but just got issue with cookie issue
i have try to by changing sameSite to lax , even httponly to false , nothing works

Try adding domain to your cookies options, and also you can pass preflight attribute inside cors

i tried this too even not working ..... please guide me bro
